# Color scheme for histogram and curve comparisions?

Tags: data-visualization

I'm making a comparison between the model I build and the data (empirical distribution), using various plots, like this:

[image]

1. Histogram and probability densiti function (PDF)
2. CDF
3. CDF at different axis (Weibull Axis)

The bule color is the data (empirical distribution), the black and red curve is the model.

The problem is that, what color scheme should I chose?

I mean, in the 1st plot, I use black to represent model, but in 2nd, and 3rd plot, I use red instead, because it contrasts better with blue dots. I'm afraid this inconsistancy would result in confusion, because there are only 2 type of data (Model vs. Empirical), yet I used 3 colors:

UPDATE:

After changing the black to red

[image]

Comment: I agree with your consistency argument, and would probably change the black curve in the leftmost plot to red (I think changing the red to black in the other plots would make them harder to read).  Otherwise I think these look pretty good.

Comment: @MatthewDrury Yes, I tried changing the red to black. It's just hard to read. I'll update with your suggestion.

Comment: If there is only the slightest chance of your results getting printed, I would ensure the colors also work when the print is in grayscale. In such cases, a very, very light gray for the data distribution, a thicker line in medium gray for the model, and black dots (or other symbols) usually do the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

> I agree with your consistency argument, and would probably change the
>   black curve in the leftmost plot to red (I think changing the red to
>   black in the other plots would make them harder to read). Otherwise I
>   think these look pretty good.

Comment: I've copied this comment by @MatthewDrury as a community wiki answer because the comment is, more or less, an answer to this question. We have a dramatic gap between answers and questions. At least part of the problem is that some questions are answered in comments: if comments which answered the question were answers instead, we would have fewer unanswered questions.